# Get ListViewItem DataTemplate when a ItemTemplateSelector is used

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datatemplate, itemtemplateselector

I have a `ListView` where I use a `ItemTemplateSelector`. Inside my `DataTemplate` is a `MediaElement`. I want to be able to start/pause the Video when I click on the `ListViewItem`. I have the following Code so far:

```
private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as ListViewItem;
        ContentPresenter contentPresenter = UIMGR.UIHelper.GetVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(item);
        DataTemplate myDataTemplate = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
        MediaElement myMediaElement = (MediaElement)myDataTemplate.FindName("meSender", contentPresenter);
        if(myMediaElement != null)
        {

        }
    }
```

But my `ContentTemplate` is `null`. How can I access the `DataTemplate` of my `ListViewItem`?

Comment: Shouldn't `GetVisualChild<MediaElement>(item)` also work?

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you.